# Implement in MIPS assembler the check if a given fiscal code is correct

Tags: assembly, comparison, mips

Well I have one Assignment to do Its like this: Implement in MIPS assembler the check if a given italian fiscal code is correct. The check should recalculate the "check letter" at the end of the fiscal code and compare it with the code that is present.

When you write it in assembler, there are some tricky things to consider:
 - How do you store an Array in MIPS assembly?
 - How can you ask for user input? (Hint: use a syscall, you will find a lot of examples on the web how to do it)
 - How can you iterate through the array character by character?
 - How can you calculate the right sums?
 - How can you compare the result with the given letter?
What I have tried so far is just taking input and printing, no clue how to do the rest.

```
.data 
       Array1:  .ascii   "Kynmmm91s11z236p"
        Array2: .space 16 
            Promt: .asciiz "Enter the fiscal code:\n"  
            Line: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:

    la $a0,Promt    
    la $t2,Array1
    li $v0,4   # prints what ever is in prompt with syscall
    syscall

    move $a0,$t2
    li $v0,4   # prints what ever is in prompt with syscall
    syscall

   la $a0,Array2    
   li $a1,20   
    li $v0,8    
   syscall

    la $t0,Array2  # BASE ADDRESS OF ARRAY   
    li $t1,4    
    lw $a0,0($t0) #***MOVED THIS OUT***     
    Loop:
        add $t0,$t0,$t1         
            beq $a0,0, Exit         
            la $a0, Array2       
            li $v0,4        
            syscall         

            li $a0, 0  #****ADDED THIS LINE****         
            j Loop

    Exit:
        li $v0,10   
            syscall

           # ***Kynmmm91s11z236p***
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused with why you la $a0, Array constantly in your loop. When you previously did this and then lw the 0($t0) into it. Maybe I am confusing myself here. Can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: For example "Kynmmm91s11z236p" this is a fiscal code which is stored in an array 1 and then we create array 2, for which we take values from the keyboard. In the end we compare the both arrays if the both are equal then the fiscal code is correct.

Comment: where in your code are you storing the fiscal code?

Comment: Can you explain this line as well? "The check should recalculate the "check letter" at the end of the fiscal code and compare it with the code that is present."

Comment: Roughly I added : Array1:  .ascii   "Kynmmm91s11z236p"    As I dont know exactly what to do.

Comment: About this line : "The check should recalculate the "check letter" at the end of the fiscal code and compare it with the code that is present" I am also uncertain, probably have to ask the professor.

Comment: If my answer provided a solution for your problem, please mark it as the solution by clicking the green arrow near the post score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second Edit:

Okay, this now works correctly for your example check code but I cannot guarantee that there are not hidden bugs or any mistakes. It will print either correct or incorrect for the control code given the 16 character fiscal code.

It is very repetitive as I could not find very many patterns in the odd positions that and I did not want to do anything to complex. I made it fairly simple and commented it thoroughly.

Any further questions or comments don't hesitate to ask.

```
# Italian Fiscal Code Calculation in MIPS

        .data
            ArraySpace:     .space 18
            lookupTableOdd: .ascii "10579"
            msgOk:          .asciiz "\nCorrect control code!"
            msgFail:        .asciiz "\nIncorrect control code!"
        .text

main:
    li $v0, 8                       # read string to store into ArraySpace 
    la $a0, ArraySpace              # load address of fiscal value attempt
    li $a1, 18                      # length 16 + '\n'
    syscall                         # tell system to read string                
    addi $t2, $a1, -2               # length of string
    li $t3, 0                       # i = 0 (our string iterator)
    jal loop                        # actually loop through input string

    li $t9, 26                      # load 26 for divison
    div $t5, $t9                    # divide total in $t5 by 26
    mflo $t4                        # move result into $t4 

    jal controlCode                 # calculate control code
    move $t5, $t4                   # move our calculated check code to $t5
    jal checkCode                   # check control code

    li $v0, 10                      # exit code
    syscall                         # terminate nicely

checkCode:
    addi $t2, $t2, -1               # backup to last index in string
    lbu $t4, ArraySpace($t2)        # load the control code of the input string  (last index)
    blt $t4, 65, endLoop            # should not get something below 65
    bgt $t4, 122, endLoop           # not valid character above 122
    addi $t4, $t4, -65              # get alphabet value 0-25
    bge $t4, 32, case_convert_ch    # if a-z we have to sub 32
    beq $t5, $t4, checkOk           # checkcode is equal to calculated code
    j checkFail                     # else fail

checkFail:
    li $v0, 4                       # print fail
    la $a0, msgFail                 # load failed code message
    syscall                         # print it
    j endLoop                       

case_convert_ch:
    addi $t4, $t4, -32              # make lowercase 'A'-'a'=-32
    beq $t4, $t5, checkOk           # if equal print ok
    j checkFail                     # else fail

controlCode:
    bgt  $t4, 4, checkDigit         # >4 is two digit value
    lbu  $t4, lookupTableOdd($t4)   # fetch corresponding value
    addi $t4, $t4, -48              # get digit value
    j endLoop

checkDigit:                         # this is for 5 to 9 in odd positions
    sub $t4, $t4, 5                 # value - 5
    mul $t9, $t4, 2                 # multiply this by 2
    li $t4, 13                      # the base is 13
    add $t4, $t4, $t9               # 13 + factor of 2
    j endLoop

case_convert_cc:
    addi $t4, $t4, -32              # uppercase: 'A'-'a'=-32
    bgt  $t4, 4, oddDigit           # >4 is two digit value
    lbu  $t4, lookupTableOdd($t4)   # fetch corresponding value
    addi $t4, $t4, -48              # get digit value
    j endLoop

checkOk:
    li $v0, 4                       # print string
    la $a0, msgOk                   # load ok message
    syscall                         # print it
    j endLoop

loop:
    bge  $t3, $t2, endLoop          # if greater than length of string end
    andi $t8, $t3, 1                # logical AND result into $t2 (even = 0, odd = 1)
    beq $t8, $zero, evenLoop        # on even positions goto evenLoop
    j oddLoop                       # on odd positions goto oddLoop

evenLoop:
    lbu $t4, ArraySpace($t3)        # load the i index of the input string
    blt $t4, 48, endLoop            # should not get something below 48
    bgt $t4, 57, evenCharLoop       # not a digit
    addi $t4, $t4, -48              # get digit value
    j continueLoop

oddLoop:
    lbu $t4, ArraySpace($t3)        # load the i index of the input string
    blt $t4, 48, endLoop            # should not get something below 48
    bgt $t4, 57, oddCharLoop        # not a digit

    addi $t4, $t4, -48              # get digit value
    bgt  $t4, 4, oddDigit           # >4 is two digit value
    lbu  $t0, lookupTableOdd($t4)   # fetch corresponding value
    addi $t4, $t0, -48              # get digit value
    j continueLoop

oddDigit:                           # this is for 5 to 9 in odd positions
    sub $t4, $t4, 5                 # value - 5
    mul $t9, $t4, 2                 # multiply this by 2
    li $t4, 13                      # the base is 13
    add $t4, $t4, $t9               # 13 + factor of 2
    j continueLoop

evenCharLoop:
    blt $t4, 65, endLoop            # should not get something below 65
    bgt $t4, 122, endLoop           # not valid char
    addi $t4, $t4, -65              # get alphabet value
    bge $t4, 32, case_convert_even  # if a-z we have to sub 32
    add $t5, $t5, $t4               # add the alpha value A-Z to our sum
    add $t3, $t3, 1                 # i++
    j loop

oddCharLoop:
    blt $t4, 65, endLoop            # should not get something below 65
    bgt $t4, 122, endLoop           # not valid char
    addi $t4, $t4, -65              # get alphabet value
    bge $t4, 32, case_convert_odd   # if a-z we have to sub 32
    j oddProcess

## this should probably be done better but I did not find many patterns ##
oddDigitCheck:
    ble  $t4, 9, oddDigit           # F>=x<=J is two digit value of factor 2
    sub $t4, $t4, 10                # >=K
    blt $t4, 2, KL                  # 0-K 1-L
    blt $t4, 4, MN                  # 2-M 3-N
    beq $t4, 4, O                   # 4-O
    blt $t4, 7, PQ                  # 5-P 6-Q
    beq $t4, 7, R                   # 7-R
    blt $t4, 11, STU                # 8-S 9-T 10-U
    beq $t4, 11, V                  # 11-V
    beq $t4, 12, W                  # 12-W
    blt $t4, 16, XYZ                # 13-X 14-Y 15-Z

oddProcess:
    bgt  $t4, 4, oddDigitCheck      # >E could be two digit value
    lbu  $t0, lookupTableOdd($t4)   # fetch corresponding value (A-E)
    addi $t0, $t0, -48              # get digit value
    add $t5, $t5, $t0               # add the digit to our sum
    add $t3, $t3, 1                 # i++
    j loop

case_convert_even:
    addi $t4, $t4, -32              # to uppercase: 'A'-'a'=-32
    j continueLoop

case_convert_odd:
    addi $t4, $t4, -32              # to uppercase: 'A'-'a'=-32
    j oddProcess

endLoop:
    jr $ra                          # jump and return

XYZ:
    sub $t4, $t4, 13                # X or Y or Z
    li $t9, 25                      # base is 25
    sub $t4, $t9, $t4               # 25 - (0,1,2)
    j continueLoop

W:
    li $t4, 22                      # W = 22
    j continueLoop

V:
    li $t4, 10                      # V = 10
    j continueLoop

STU:
    sub $t4, $t4, 8                 # S or T or U
    mul $t9, $t4, 2                 # mult by 2
    li  $t4, 12                     # base of 12        
    add $t4, $t4, $t9               # add factor
    j continueLoop

R:
    li $t4, 8                       # R = 8
    j continueLoop

PQ:
    sub $t4, $t4, 5                 # P or Q
    mul $t9, $t4, 3                 # mult by 3
    li  $t4, 3                      # base of 3     
    add $t4, $t4, $t9               # add factor
    j continueLoop

O:
    li $t4, 11                      # O = 11
    j continueLoop

MN:
    sub $t4, $t4, 2                 # M or N
    mul $t9, $t4, 2                 # mult by 2
    li  $t4, 18                     # base of 18        
    add $t4, $t4, $t9               # add factor
    j continueLoop

KL:
    mul $t9, $t4, 2                 # mult by 2
    li  $t4, 2                      # base of 2     
    add $t4, $t4, $t9               # add factor
    j continueLoop

continueLoop:
    add $t5, $t5, $t4               # add the digit to our sum
    add $t3, $t3, 1                 # i++
    j loop
```

Comment: there is a description on how to calculate the italian tax code on: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnethell.it%2Farticles%2FCalcoloCodiceFiscale.aspx

Comment: The response I got from the Prof on "The check should recalculate the "check letter" at the end of the fiscal code and compare it with the code that is present."                                         The task is that you take the fiscal code as input from the keyboard for example
Kynmmm91s11z236p :
 
"p" is the checking code, a letter that is calculated using all the other letters. You should calculate it according to the instructions in the first link. Then You compare what you calculated with the letter that you got from the user and output the result.

Comment: Thank you very much Wazy so far you helped me a lot.

Comment: This actually seems a little confusing unless I'm reading it wrong. So we have a input fiscal string and one stored in memory. We then validate the input one by recalculating the check code then compare it to the original one in memory or? Also put your latest code above if you are still working on it.

Comment: No I actually I understood it wrong first up. We have just one code that we take from the keyboard as an input. e.g Kynmmm91s11z236p . So the last alphabetic charachter is based on the previous 16 letters.                                                          Odd ……….
Even …………………..
Sum : = Number
Number/26 =  last letter.            So we have to compare the aphabetic last charachter taken as an input from keyboard with our calculation based on first 15 charachters. Here is the link where you can see   http://www.dotnethell.it/articles/CalcoloCodiceFiscale.aspx

Comment: Since you know the length of that code you can easily take the last byte and compare it to the one you will calculate from the rest of it. Make sure you use .space 18 for the 16 character code and the newline and the null terminating character. I will work on this after work today if you do not manage to resolve this.

Comment: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnethell.it%2Farticles%2FCalcoloCodiceFiscale.aspx this is the english version of the Italian Fiscal code .. How it is composed and how the last character is determined.. You can have a look at it ... Thanks very much.

Comment: Well still I couldn't. Can you help Wazy? It would be great, thanks

Comment: Post your latest code and the weekend is coming up so I may have some time. This isn't a very easy or quick project so I have to find time.

Comment: I have posted my code a couple of days ago. Ii you can help me.. I have 4 more days. I am very grateful to you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what it could be like..

```
.data 

                ArraySpace: .space 18
                Prompt: .asciiz "Enter the fiscal code: "  
                Line: .asciiz "\n"

    .text

    # $a0 = buffer, $a1 = length

    main:   
        la $a0, Prompt          # user prompt
        li $v0, 4               # print string
        syscall

        li $v0, 8               # read string to store into ArraySpace 
        la $a0, ArraySpace      # load address of fiscal value attempt
        li $a1, 18              # length 16 + '\n' + '\0'
        syscall

        la $a0, ArraySpace      # load user string
        li $v0, 4               # print string
        syscall

        # An example of Fiscal code = Kynmmm91s11z236p
```

I actuall I have no idea in MIPS.
SO I will write the algorithm for the calculation of Last letter of Fiscal Code..

```
I dont know how to translate this algorithm in MIPS.

    Formula for the calculation of last letter of Fiscal code.
    Even position Values ………….
    ODD position Values …………….
    Sum : = Number/26 =  last letter.

   Fiscal Code  : Kynmmm91s11z236p

    EVEN positions values
    K   n     m    9    s   1   2    6  
    10+ 13 +  12 + 9  +  18+ 1 +  2  +6 =  71 

    ODD  position values
    Y       m      m      1    1     z    3 
    24  + 18 +  18 +0 +  0 +23 + 7 =  90
    I61/26 = 6 
   As 6 is at odd position so 6 = 15.
 According to the last letter table 15 = P. Which is correct.
```

Comment: Write the algorithm in another language first. C/Java etc.

Comment: I dont understand this: how can 6 be at a odd position and thus = 15? Check the modified code I posted it is for the most part complete and calculates that 6.

Comment: The control code should always be looked up in the odd table. I will address this momentarily in the code.

Comment: Thank you very Much Wazy .. I admire your effort.. It was helpful